# Capitalize the first letter, lower case the rest

Tags: c++, lowercase, capitalize, tolower, toupper

I am asking a user to enter their name and I want to automatically format the name so that, no matter how they enter the name, it will appear as capital first letter, lower case the rest. For example, if they enter "joHN" the program will still output their name as "John."

I have the following code for their name input:

```
string name;
cout << "Please enter your first name: ";
cin >> name;
```

I am assuming I will have to use the toupper and tolower commands, but I am really unsure how to write something to adjust each character in the string.

Comment: Only a comment for most answerers: I think to suggest an STL algorithm based on iterators and other C++ machinery is not a good answer for somebody who is asking about upper/lower functions. He/she is a C++ newbbie. Thats why I have not mentioned `std::transform()`, which is the most elegant solution so far.

Comment: @Manu343726, true, but not everyone that comes here will be a complete "newbie".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Standard Library provides the C functions [`std::toupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and [`std::tolower()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower) which return the upper/lower case of the specified ASCII character. So your problem could be solved with a simple for loop:

```
if( !name.empty() )
{
    name[0] = std::toupper( name[0] );

    for( std::size_t i = 1 ; i < name.length() ; ++i )
        name[i] = std::tolower( name[i] );
}
```

Comment: `!name.empty()` is more efficient than `name.size() > 0`

Comment: @Alex. Thanks. We are refinning the answer bit a bit. This seems like a wiki :)

Comment: There are also the equivalent C++ standard functions [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/toupper) and [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/tolower) which are wrappers around the respective methods of the [`std::ctype`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/ctype) facet.

Comment: When I try this I am given the error "'length' undeclared (first use this function)." I tried searching this but came up empty. Is this because I haven't assigned a max length value to string name?

Comment: @user2999339 [`std::string::length()`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) is a member function of `std::string`. There is no reason because it does not work, except you are not using `std::string`.

Comment: @Manu343726 I am using #include <iostream>, <algorithm>, and <string>. Is this what you meant? You are right that I am completely new to this, so please forgive me if I'm missing what you're saying.

Comment: @user2999339 yes, thats what I mean. So your includes are correct and you are using `std::string`. As I said before, there is no reason wich explains why `length()` does not work. Could you provide the exactly compiler error?

Comment: @Manu343726 
`
Program.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Program.cpp:25: error: 'length' undeclared (first use this function)
Program.cpp:25: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in.)

make.exe: *** [Program.o] Error 1'code'`

Comment: @Manu343726 when I changed "length" to "name.length" it worked perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @user2999339 sorry, was my fault :(

Answer (score 5):

The simplest solution is probably to make the whole word lower-case first, then make the first character upper case.

C++ has some [nice algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) in the standard library. For this I suggest [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) together with [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower). And there's of course [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) for the last part:

```
if (!name.empty())
{
    std::transform(std::begin(name), std::end(name), std::begin(name),
                   [](char const& c)
                   {
                      return std::tolower(c);
                   });

    name[0] = std::toupper(name[0]);
}
```

Comment: Please wrap `std::tolower` into a lambda, as cppreference suggested. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/55687044/5376789.

Answer (score 2):

Assume there is no spaces at the beginning, you can use [`std::toupper()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) and [`std::tolower()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower):

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < name.length(); i++)
    name[i] = i==0? std::toupper(name[i]) : std::tolower(name[i]);
```

More efficient by longer code:

```
if (name.length()>0)
{
    name[0] = std::toupper(name[0]) ;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < name.length(); i++)
        name[i] = std::tolower(name[i]);
}
```

And finally, this code skips first spaces (if exists)

```
std::string capital(std::string name)
{
    if (!name.empty())
    {
        auto i = name.begin();

        while (i != name.end() && std::isspace(*i))
            ++i;

        if (i == name.end())
            return name;

        *i = std::toupper(*i++);

        std::transform(i, name.end(), i, ::tolower);
    }

    return name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

An other fast solution

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string> 

if (!name.empty()) // Edit : Add the verification
{
   std::transform(name.begin(), name.end(), name.begin(), ::tolower);
   name[0] = std::toupper(name[0]);
}
```

Comment: As @M.M. pointed out in my answer, that invokes UB

Comment: I think to make this actually work I would have to switch around lines  6 (name[0]...) and 7 (std::transform...).

Comment: You are totally right, sorry for the mistake !